# Vectorization of feature scaling

Tags: octave, vectorization

I want to feature scale a matrix (X) with 2 columns. I am using mean normalization, and I wrote the following lines in Octave:

```
X_norm = X
mu = mean(X);
sigma = std(X);
X_norm(:,1) = (X_norm(:,1) .- mu(:,1)) ./ sigma(:,1);
X_norm(:,2) = (X_norm(:,2) .- mu(:,2)) ./ sigma(:,2);
```

Can you please let me know a cleaner way to vectorize these calculation?

I checked my code by comparing with the result from `zscore(X)` and they matched - i.e. a `sum(X_norm - zscore(X))` returned me 0 0.

I am constrained to not use `zscore()`, and hence the question.

Sample data as follows:

```
2104      3
1600      3
2400      3
1416      2
3000      4
1985      4
1534      3
1427      3
1380      3
1494      3
1940      4
2000      3
1890      3
4478      5
1268      3
2300      4
1320      2
1236      3
2609      4
3031      4
1767      3
1888      2
1604      3
1962      4
3890      3
1100      3
1458      3
2526      3
2200      3
2637      3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simply do:

```
X_norm = (X .- mean(X,1)) ./ std(X,0,1);
```

Comment: Much appreciated.

Comment: how to make this as generalised version?

Comment: why mean(X,*1*) ? help says it finds mean along the DIM 1., could you please clear the concept ? similarly std(X,0,1) ?

Comment: @faztp12 mean(x,1) calculates the mean along dimension 1 (i.e. rows). In other words, at the end of the operation, dim 1 will have been reduced to a single row (i.e. a singleton dimension) by taking the mean over all rows. Similarly with std.  However, the reason the above snippet works has nothing to do with mean(X,1) vs mean(X) ... mean(X) acts along dimension 1 by default anyway. The reason the above snippet works and you don't have to do each column separately, is because octave supports [broadcasting](https://octave.org/doc/interpreter/Broadcasting.html)

Answer (score 1):

During cross validation faced zero division issue.
This worked for me.

```
mu = mean(X);
X_norm = X - mu;
sigma = std(X);

% Skip zero div
sigmaZeroIdx = sigma == 0;
sigma(1,sigmaZeroIdx) = 1;

X_norm = X_norm ./ sigma;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could apply a for loop for N size of features.

```
X_norm = X;
mu = zeros(1, size(X, 2));
sigma = zeros(1, size(X, 2));

for iter = 1:num_iters;
  mu(1,iter) = mean(X_norm(:,iter)); 
  X_norm(:,iter) = X_norm(:,iter) .- mu(1,iter);
  
  sigma(1,iter) = std(X_norm(:,iter));  
  X_norm(:,iter) = X_norm(:,iter) ./ mu(1,iter); 
end
```